# node.js + serial code not work consistently

Tags: javascript, node.js

i tried to calculate root mean square using node.js, trying to be smart to make some kind of high resolution realtime measurement of stuff from serial port.

the code doesnt really matter. but each time i try to run this multiple times but it output totally different rms output value, sometimes very big, sometimes very small, NaN, etc.
the question is:
why? how? is there any node.js quirk i miss? like inter-process shared memory allocation?

it's fixed after i rewrite the program(some edit) or waiting for some time

re running a program should do the same thing everytime, right?

btw i'm using nodeserial for serial communication, at 500k baud

actual code may be posted later if you want

edit: the code

```js
var math = require('mathjs');

var fs = require('fs');

// serving the static html "client"
var http = require('http');
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var serve = serveStatic("./");
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var done = finalhandler(req, res);
  serve(req, res, done);
});
//  socket.io

var app = require('express')();
var http2 = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http2);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('client connected');
});

/* CONSOLE INTERFACE, USED TO MANUALLY INSERT SOME KIND OF VARIABLES*/
//stdin interaction
var stdin = process.openStdin();
var command = '';
var commandmode = false;
var bufferdata;
var command = 0;

//serial stuff

var serialport = require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
//portName = process.argv[2];
portName = "COM4"
  //parsing commandline argument as comport name


var myPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
  baudRate: 500000, // choose between: 115200, 57600, 38400, 19200, 9600, 4800, 2400, 1800, 1200, 600, 300, 200, 150, 134, 110, 75, or 50
  // look for return and newline at the end of each data packet:
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
myPort.on('data', sendSerialData);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);

var datacount = 0;

function showPortOpen() {
  console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.options.baudRate);
}

var timestamp;
var timestampold;
var dt;

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = "0000" + num;
  return s.substring(s.length - size);
}

function padd(num, size) {
  var s = "00000000" + num;
  return s.substring(s.length - size);
}

var vrms = [];
var irms = [];
var torq = [];
var speed = [];
var vraw = [];
var iraw = [];

function sendSerialData(data) {
  if (datacount === 0) {
    timestampold = Date.now();
  }
  if (datacount === 10) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  if (datacount === 1000) {
    timestamp = Date.now();
    dt = timestamp - timestampold;
    var samplerate;
    var datalength = data.length + 1;
    samplerate = datacount * 1000 / dt;
    var troughput = datalength * samplerate;
    var troughputp = 800 * troughput / 500000;
    console.log(datacount + " data has been recorded. time elapsed:" + dt + ", samplerate:" + samplerate + " troughput:" + troughput + "/" + troughputp + "%");
  }

  var parseddata = data.split(",");
  vraw.push(parseInt(parseddata[0], 16));
  iraw.push(parseInt(parseddata[1], 16));
  torq.push(parseInt(parseddata[2], 16));
  speed.push(parseInt(parseddata[3], 16));
  rmsfast(vraw[datacount], iraw[datacount]);
  //var rawlog = padd(datacount,8) + "," + pad(vraw[datacount],4) + ","+ pad(iraw[datacount],4) +","+ pad(speed[datacount],4)+","+ pad(torq[datacount],4);
  //var rawlog = padd(datacount, 8) + "," + vraw[datacount] + "," + iraw[datacount] + "," + speed[datacount] + "," + torq[datacount] + ">>" + vrms[datacount] + "," + irms[datacount];
  //fs.appendFileSync('raw.txt', rawlog);
  //console.log(rawlog);

  ++datacount;
}

function showPortClose() {
  console.log('port closed.');
}

function showError(error) {
  console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}

var varray = [0];

// zero setup;

var mid = 2048; //ideal; changed on zerocross detection

/* the data from microcontroller is as such: VVV,III,TTT,NNN
CC = COMMAND/RUNNING MODE
VVVV = VOLTAGE READING
IIII = CURRENT READING
TTTT = TORQUE READING
NNNN = SPEED (RPM) READING
Z = IS ZERO(0=false,1=voltage,2=current)
delta t between data (microsecond);
 */
var bufferV = [0];
var bufferI = [0];
var datacount;

var dataindex; // index of data called on the below stuff

var rmslength = 80;
var sigmaVsquared = 0;
var sigmaIsquared = 0;

var lastVvalue = 0;
var lastIvalue = 0;
var Vrms = 0;
var avgV = 0;
var avgI = 0;

function rmsfast(newVoltage, newCurrent) { // example use = rmsfast(data,buffer,)
  var newSqVoltage = Math.pow(newVoltage, 2);
  var newSqCurrent = Math.pow(newCurrent, 2);


  bufferV.push(newSqVoltage);
  if (bufferV.length === 80) {
    lastVvalue = bufferV.shift();
  } else {
    //lastVvalue = newSqVoltage;
  }
  avgV += ((newSqVoltage - lastVvalue) / 80);
  Vrms = math.sqrt(avgV);

  bufferI.push(newSqCurrent);
  lastIvalue = bufferI.shift();
  avgI += (newSqCurrent - lastIvalue) / 80;
  var Irms = math.sqrt(avgI);
  var darn = math.sqrt(4000000);

  if (datacount < 1000) {
    var darz = Number.isInteger(newSqVoltage);
    var vavg = avgV;
    var vrmss = vrms;
    console.log(newVoltage + "\t---" + avgV + "\t---" + Vrms);
  }
  if (datacount === 1000) {
    myPort.close(process.exit());


  }

  vrms.push(Vrms);
  irms.push(Irms);
}
server.listen(2000); // listening to the port

stdin.addListener("data", function(cons) { //"listening" to stdin
  command = cons.toString().trim();
});
```

Comment: Ok, so you have code that doesn't work consistently... Of course we need to see it.

Comment: sorry, thats not the best code i can think of. i can do better with async and stuff. 
today will make every used value have its own variable i think